# Techniques for repairing asbestos siding with GAF Weatherside fiber cement?

Tags: siding, paint-removal, shingles, sheathing

My older (1930s) home is covered with asbestos siding over tar paper sheathing. Some of the siding is cracked/missing and some of the tar paper beneath it is torn.

At present I can't re-side the entire home. But GAF makes a current non-asbestos (fiber cement) product (GAF Weatherside Purity Wave) which is essentially similar to the currently installed siding. I've ordered 3 bundles, which will cover about 100 sq. ft. I want to patch the broken/missing siding areas, and then remove some rather sloppily applied old latex paint and then re-paint the entire home.

While I've patched a shingle here and there in past, I wanted to ask about the proper/best techniques for patching the tar paper sheathing under the shingles and then applying the new shingles for optimum long term performance. I also want to ask about removing the old latex paint. I have access to a pressure washer, but that stuff is awful stubborn (and, coming off in bits and pieces, it looks terrible!).

Comment: Depending on your local regulations, might need to have professionals remove the sliding, or at the least do it with full safety gear.  Will probably need permits and locate a license place to dispose of it, you can't just put it out with the regular garbage.  Removing paint from it is the most dangerous and might need the area sealed in a tent.

Comment: Can read this question for more information, almost the same as yours.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/141983/is-my-plan-to-safely-remove-asbestos-siding-sound?rq=1